# VS2012 javascript intellisense works only with explicit invocation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense

I am trying to make the new vs2012 javascript intellisense work.

At first I noticed it was not working because resharper intellisense was enabled. I tried to completely suspend resharper, and I got a better situation, but still buggy.

I added the _references.js file with a couple of references (jquery and angularjs). I switched, in the options, to Implicit (web) settings so it reads the _references.js file.

I added an empty js file. Intellisense only appears if I CTRL+SPACE (for method and types list) or CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE (for method parameters list) but it doesn't appear when I start typing, nor when I type a dot or open a round bracket.

I don't really know what's the problem. Resharper is out of the way so everything should work.

The edition is Vs2012 premium 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL.

Other extensions installed:

- Web Developer Tools (which I also got on a web developer express edition on another computer, and on that installation intellisense works fine)
- Web Essentials 2012 (disabled)
- Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript (which I can't disable nor uninstall)
- Git Source Control Provider (which I hardly think could be related)
- xUnit.net runner for visual studio 2012 (again, hardly related)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matteo - are you still having these issues with VS2012 JavaScript IntelliSense? - Jordan, Microsoft Visual Studio PM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ReSharper intellisense and Visual Studio intellisense are two completely different beasts.

If you have problems with ReSharper intellisense, then please describe what kind of a problem do you have with it. Does it work with Ctrl-Space? If it works, but it doesn't get invoked automatically, then please check settings at `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | Autopopup`.

If you prefer Visual Studio intellisense, please go to `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | General`, select `Limited ReSharper intellisense` and turn off JavaScript there. Then ensure that `Tools | Options -> Text Editor | JavaScript | General -> Auto list members` is turned on.

Comment: I thank you for your answer but it seems that you didn't read my post carefully. I tried to completely disable resharper (by hitting suspend) and still intellisense is buggy, only working with ctrl-space and ctrl-shift-space. I know I can disable it partially as you described (that's the first shot I gave at it). I need to know what could be interfering with visual studio intellisense besides resharper, which seems NOT to be the cause.

Comment: But did you read my answer carefully? Especially this part: "ensure that Tools | Options -> Text Editor | JavaScript | General -> Auto list members is turned on". And please note once again that problems that you have with ReSharper and without ReSharper are two different problems. Most likely if you defeat a problem without ReSharper you'd still have a problem with ReSharper. So please also give us details about your problems with ReSharper.

Comment: I did read that, that option is enabled of course. My problem is exectly the same if in resharper I turn on selective intellisense enabling all languages except javascript or if I suspend resharper entirely. That's why I think resharper is not the cause.

Comment: But if you turn on javascript intellisense in ReSharper, what problems do you have?

Comment: Resharper's javascript intellisense is just not as good as the new vs2012 one. It's still better for other languages, it just doesn't cut it for JS. You just need to try them both to realize how much better it is the new vs2012 js intellisense.